# ReflectionException: Class AppBundle\Core\getConstants does not exist in YamlTrait

Tags: php, class, symfony, constants, traits

I want to use `\ReflectionClass` in a PHP Trait to take out all constants of `AppBundle\Core\CoreInterface` and have them in an `array`. I'm using this `array` to populate a property I'm using in several controllers that `use YamlTrait;`.

So I'm going like this:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Core;

use AppBundle\Core\CoreInterface;

trait YamlTrait
{
    protected $ymlFiles = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $constants = (new \ReflectionClass('AppBundle\Core\CoreInterface'))->getConstants();
        $this->ymlFiles = $constants;
    }
}
```

This works well and `var_dump($this->ymlFiles);` outputs:

```
array (size=5)
  'YML_CITATIONS' => string 'citations' (length=9)
  'YML_PARCOURS' => string 'parcours' (length=8)
  'YML_COMPETENCES' => string 'competences' (length=11)
  'YML_REALISATIONS' => string 'realisations' (length=12)
  'YML_CONTACT' => string 'contact' (length=7)
```

Now, given the fact that [`var_dump(CoreInterface::class);`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name) outputs:

```
C:\wamp\www\sf2\src\AppBundle\Core\YamlTrait.php:12:string 'AppBundle\Core\CoreInterface' (length=28)
```

I then tought that I would be able to do:

```
$constants = (new \ReflectionClass(CoreInterface::class))->getConstants();
```

But this outputs the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message '**Class AppBundle\Core\getConstants does not exist**'

I also tried the following to no avail:

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass(CoreInterface::class);
$this->ymlFiles = $reflection->getConstants();
```

So what's wrong with my code? Is this because of a misusage of Traits in PHP I wouldn't be aware of?

Comment: Not sure if this helps but the `trait` doc says that you cannot instantiate a trait on its own. But you have a `__construct` in your trait. Could that be the reason?

Comment: @DipenShah: I'm not instanciating the trait on its own. It rather overrides the Controllers' constructor to populate `$this->ymlFiles`. I have indeed access to this constants array in my Controllers actions (when I use plain string as `CoreInterface` FQN in the `\ReflectionClass` instanciation).

Comment: What PHP version are you on?

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm assuming you have a file `CoreInterface.php`

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Core;

class CoreInterface
{
    const YML_CITATIONS = 'citations';
    const YML_PARCOURS = 'parcours';
    const YML_COMPETENCES = 'competences';
    const YML_REALISATIONS = 'realisations';
    const YML_CONTACT = 'contact';
}
```

and a trait `YamlTrait.php`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Trait;
trait YamlTrait
{
    protected $ymlFiles = [];
    public function __construct()
    {
        $constants = (new \ReflectionClass('AppBundle\Controller\CoreInterface'))->getConstants();
        $this->ymlFiles = $constants;
    }

    public function getYmlFiles()
    {
        return $this->ymlFiles;
    }
}
```

You can call your trait in a Controller such as AcmeController.php as:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

use AppBundle\Trait\YamlTrait; //Trait you just created

class AcmeController extends Controller
{
    use YamlTrait;

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        /*This wil get you the YmlFiles array*/
        $ymlFiles = $this->getYmlFiles();

        //Do somtething with your array

        return array();
    }
}
```

This line `$ymlFiles = $this->getYmlFiles();` will return the array as you mentioned:

```
array (size=5)
  'YML_CITATIONS' => string 'citations' (length=9)
  'YML_PARCOURS' => string 'parcours' (length=8)
  'YML_COMPETENCES' => string 'competences' (length=11)
  'YML_REALISATIONS' => string 'realisations' (length=12)
  'YML_CONTACT' => string 'contact' (length=7)
```

The error you are receiving when trying to call `CoreInterface::class` is because the double colon '::' (Scope Resolution Operator) is used to access static methods or constants, such as `CoreInterface::YML_CITATIONS` or `CoreInterface::YML_PARCOURS`, see below:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Comment: I get your point but, then, why doing `var_dump(CoreInterface::class);` outputs `AppBundle\Core\CoreInterface`?

Comment: Well, looking at the documetation in [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php#refsect1-reflectionclass.newinstanceargs-errors)

It seems that the ReflectionException is thrown if the constructor of the class passed does not exist or if it isn't public.

Checking the class operator [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) it should return a string with the name of the class and the namespace.. but oddly it isn't working... it's returning `AppBundle\Core\ ` when it should be returning `AppBundle\Core\CoreInterface `

Comment: A comment in the second php.net link says to correctly check if the namespace has been correctly declared in the use statement  (something like `use AppBundle\Core\CoreInterface` before calling `CoreInterface::class`). If not correct, the ::class keyword could be returning a wrong value.